# ASP.NET w/ C# SortedList

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create a SortedList that holds multiple variables? I want to keep multiple instances of (date, height, weight).

Comment: That does not make much sense...

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a class that contains the fields you want to store.

```
class MyVariables {
    DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    double Height { get; set; }
    double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

and then use that in your sorted list

```
var list = new SortedList<string, MyVariables>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of your object.

```
public class MyItem
{
  public decimal Weight {get;set;}
  public decimal Height {get;set;}
  public DateTime TheDate {get;set;}
} 

List<MyItem> myItems = new List<MyItems>();
var mySortedList = myItems.OrderBy(p => p.Weight);
```

Then you can sort it with linq perhaps.

Comment: There's a class called `SortedList` which is confusingly a type of dictionary.  Actually there are two classes with the same name, one in `System.Collections` and another in `System.Collections.Generic`.